# send data to android set

Tags: php, android

how to send data from a php page that is open in browser to a particular person who has android set with him.The person is connected to the Internet and me also.i know the person IMEI number.kindly tell me all the possible solutions.please i am new to android

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way is to use c2dm - http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html

Comment: c2dm has many other things that you must take into account like must have 1 logged account etc ..Is there any other way? can i embedd some code in php page?